# Facebook Realtime Update Subscriptions and new app users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to subscribe to receive an update when new users authorize the app? Just like the Deauthorize Callback URL but for authorizes. I have tried the Facebook Realtime Update Subscriptions but it seems it will notify only when an existing users changes information in his profile.

Answer (score 0):

All of the connections you can subscribe to are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ - the Application object is not one, nor is there a connection of the application object which returns a list of users

Since you need to make an API call to register each new user anyway, why not log the new user into your own system at that point? or at the time they first authorise your app?

Comment: I'll be doing this from a mobile app, so I thought it would be better in therms of bandwith consumption this way. The other way would be what you suggests: the user authorizes the facebook app inside the mobile app, then asks his profile information to facebook, some friends information and posts this to the server.